# Augment Reality for Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I have quite strange augment reality case to implement. Most AR frameworks I've found can be classified on 2 groups:

1. GPS based ones
2. Based on visual markers (something like a QR code) located in real world.

Basically here is a list:

- AndAr    https://code.google.com/p/andar/
- Mixare https://code.google.com/p/mixare/
- DroidAr https://code.google.com/p/droidar/

But this does not fit my case, in simple words, I do need to place visual marker flying in a room near by one or several physical assets. I do have all needed coordinates, but I don't sure how I can show marker flying 2 meters in front of a phone, because all above mentioned frameworks positioning api based on degrees, minutes and seconds. Don't sure how I can correlate those 2 coordinates system.

Answer (score 1):

I use [BeyondAR](http://beyondar.com/platform) for this. is small, simple, free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikitude SDK](http://developer.wikitude.com/download) allows you to put markers (so called GeoObjects) relative to a position. The position could be the user's position or any position defined by latitude, longitude, altitude (in your case this could be the initial user's position). The relative position is defined in meters north/east of the initial position.

For more information have a look at the documentation at: http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/3.0/Reference/JavaScript%20Reference/index.html

It includes both Geo-based AR and Image Recognition & Tracking.

*Disclaimer: I'm working for Wikitude*

Answer (score 0):

I use BeyondAR for this. is small, simple, free and open source. Here the linke
[BeyondAR Framework](http://beyondar.com/platform)